# Using GetX, got this error: [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected trying to implement NavigationBar (Material3)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, material3

I am trying to implement the Material3 NavigationBar widget using GetX and getting the following error:

```
Exception has occurred.
"      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
      You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
      If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx 
      or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
      (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
      If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
      "
```

My Controller:

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var currentIndex = 0.obs;
  void changeIndex(int index) {
    currentIndex.value = index;
  }
}
```

My HomeView code

```
class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final screens = [
    const MoviesView(),
    const PurchasesView(),
    const ProfileView(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(
        () => screens.elementAt(controller.currentIndex.value),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => NavigationBar(
          /*onDestinationSelected: (int index) { 
              controller.changeIndex(index); 
          },*/
          onDestinationSelected: controller.changeIndex,
          destinations: const <NavigationDestination>[
            NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.movie),
              label: 'Movies',
            ),
            NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
              label: 'Purchases',
            ),
            NavigationDestination(
              selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
              icon: Icon(Icons.people),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I initially had it working with Material2 with BottomNavigationBar since it has

> currentIndex: controller.currentIndex.value,

I believe that is missing in Material3 and possibly failing spectacularly here. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: you are using a  two times Obx and one time using wrap  Scaffold  Obx.

Comment: I have heard quite a lot about not using GetX.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final screens = [
    const MoviesView(),
    const PurchasesView(),
    const ProfileView(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(()=>
      child: Scaffold(
        body: screens.elementAt(controller.currentIndex.value),
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
          /*onDestinationSelected: (int index) { 
                controller.changeIndex(index); 
            },*/
          onDestinationSelected: controller.changeIndex,
          destinations: const <NavigationDestination>[
            NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.movie),
              label: 'Movies',
            ),
            NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
              label: 'Purchases',
            ),
            NavigationDestination(
              selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
              icon: Icon(Icons.people),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you. I this there is one last issue. Although I know the index is changing. The Navigation bar does not change at all. The body only does.